# Mvc async operation crashes iis

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, iis, asynchronous, crash

**Scenario:** Site uses Mvc async controller.

**Error:** Everytime an async end operation (like EndReceive) throws an error it also crashes IIS.

This is the type of error one should always try to catch but is the default behavior otherwise always crashing the IIS process? (don't know if i should leave it or start more in depth troubleshooting)

Thanx,

Comment: What makes you think it is "crashing" IIS? What do you mean by crashing? What is the code in question? What OS/IIS version?

Comment: So far IIS 7 and IIS express, os win7 + win2k3.
Popup "iis process has.." and eventlog with debug info that points to async-ends (as endrecive). Crash = Workerprocess crash, iis 7 recycle the worker, iis express process needs to be restarted manually.

Comment: No code, no error reports; can't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will find the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) useful in understanding what happens under the covers.

Comment: "An unhandled exception in a thread not associated with a request will take down the process." - Thank you, that was all I wanted to know.